# remove ColorFilter / undo setColorFilter

Tags: android

How can a ColorFilter be removed or setColorFilter on a view be undone?

Comment: Please don't pad out questions with noise to defeat our quality standards detection.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Have you tried setting it to `null`?

According to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29):

> public void setColorFilter (ColorFilter cf)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Apply an arbitrary colorfilter to the image.
>   Parameters
>
> cf    the colorfilter to apply **(may be null)**

Comment: ouch. 
view.setColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, Mode.MULTIPLY); also worked

Comment: Doesn't work properly on lollipop. You should use `clearColorFilter()` instead

Comment: clearColorFilter() makes exact the same call of setColorFilter(null) in all versions of Android available now, so you are not right in second part of your statement :)

Comment: On Android 5 clearColorFilter() doesnt work for me :(

Comment: What's with people saying it doesn't work on Lollipop (API 21 or 22)?  Both the null method and the clearColorFilter() method both work on both of those APIs in my tests.  Did you test the exact same code (that you wrote) on a different API where it *did* work?

Answer (score 158):

You can call `clearColorFilter()` for the same object on which you called `setColorFilter()`.  This method is equivalent to `setColorFilter(null)`, and is arguably more readable than the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Drawable play = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_action_play_arrow);
play.clearColorFilter();
view.invalidate(); // This is helpful when you apply morethan one color filter
```

Other two answers are also there which are helpful too. But, its working for me when i invalidate view.